# Python Requests doesnt work for https proxy

Tags: python, https, proxy, python-requests

I try to use https proxy in python like this:

```
proxiesDict ={
  'http':  'http://' + proxy_line,
  'https': 'https://' + proxy_line
}


response = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json', proxies=proxiesDict, allow_redirects=False)
```

`proxy_line` is a proxy read from file in the format of ip:port. I checked this https proxy in browser and it works. But in python this code hangs for a few seconds and then i get exception:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?format=json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0425E450>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060]
```

I tried to use socks5 proxy, and it works on socks5 proxies with a PySocks installed. But for https i get this exception, can someone help me

Comment: Remove the `http://` and `https://`? Also, what does a sample `proxy_line` contain?

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks! I think it works now, but it gives me not the proxy ip for some, but other ip. Its not my ip, but its not a proxy ip either, in the browser with proxy i visit same site and see the proxy ip. `proxy_line` contains a proxy like this: 79.110.31.87:8085, and in the browser i see the same ip when visiting `api.ipify.org`, but from python i get weird addresses

Comment: It might have something to do with `allow_redirects=False`. In your browser, redirects are allowed automatically. Let me know if removing that fixes it, I'll create an answer for posterity.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i tried to `set allow_redirects=True` and it still same weird results, for example for proxy `79.110.31.87:8085` i got `{"ip":"162.220.246.230"}` i tried to ,make request to whoer.net and it display the same ip

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ nevermind, i had a system proxy set up. I removed it and now i always get my ip address instead of proxy from python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When specifying a proxy list for `requests`, the key is the protocol, and the value is the domain/ip. You don't need to specify `http://` or `https://` again, for the actual value.

So, your `proxiesDict` will be:

```
proxiesDict = {
  'http':  proxy_line,
  'https': proxy_line
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue as above except with a username:password proxy. Your answer is different from the Requests docs, which specifies to prepend 'http://'.

Comment: Requests Err:「Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://」

Comment: That error is because the urllib3 version installed in your system, the one I had, did the same thing until I downgraded to urllib3==1.25.8, the newest one requires http scheme, the old one doesn't , and some said it has bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure proxies by setting the enviroment variables:

```
$ export HTTP_PROXY="http://proxyIP:PORT"
$ export HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxyIP:PORT"
```

Then, you only need to execute your python script without proxy request.

Also, you can configure your proxy with http://user:password@host

For more information see this documentation: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: hello i need to read proxies from file, thats why i need to configure that way

Answer (score 0):

Try using pycurl this function may help:

```
import pycurl

def pycurl_downloader(url, proxy_url, proxy_usr):
    """
    Download files with pycurl
    the proxy configuration:
    proxy_url = 'http://10.0.0.0:3128'
    proxy_usr = 'user:password'
    """

    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.MAXREDIRS, 5)
    c.setopt(pycurl.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30)
    c.setopt(pycurl.AUTOREFERER, 1)

    if proxy_url: c.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, proxy_url)
    if proxy_usr: c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYUSERPWD, proxy_usr)

    content = StringIO()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, content.write)

    try:
        c.perform()
        c.close()
    except pycurl.error, error:
        errno, errstr = error
        print 'An error occurred: ', errstr

    return content.getvalue()
```

Comment: i'm gonna give it a try

Comment: I think there are typos in `if proxy:` that var does not exist. Also `conten.write`