# Proxy Error when Requests connecting from HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, python-requests, urllib3

I have been testing a site with a social media login validation. It's quite primitive aside from that I built in the ability to connect through a proxy. This works fine, including the proxy, when I run it from my box or the server the site is on. However, once I enabled https/ssl on my server and used the proxy, it stopped working with this error:

```html
  File "myprogram.py", line 274, in login
    r = self.s.get(self.url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 476, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 424, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='socialmediawebsite', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(111, 'Connection refused')))
```

I've read a solid amount and have looked through the code for requests and urllib3, but it seems more and more like I have a fundamental misunderstanding. I've tried HTTPAuth, setting verify to False, and setting environment variables. I have also tried without the proxy, and it works, which has added to my confusion. It seems to me like there might be another piece of technology required to send this https request through the proxy. Or is it just that I have to open up more ports somewhere or something equally simple?

There is one question similar to mine here: [Python Requests doesnt work for https proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166334/python-requests-doesnt-work-for-https-proxy)

But the accepted answer is factually inaccurate and didn't work for me.

What my code looks like:

```
proxies = {
  'http': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128',
}
self.s.update(proxies)
self.s.get(self.url)
```

Comment: What part of 'connection refused' don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand why this only occurs when using a proxy with ssl, or how to approach fixing it.

Comment: @aJetHorn: Unfortunately you don't show any code on how to use the proxy with SSL compared to how to use it without SSL. But what the message clearly says is that the TCP connection is refused by the proxy. This is before you even have authenticate. Given that proxy with HTTP works you might have the wrong proxy setting for HTTPS while the correct one with HTTP.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for your reply. My mistake on not including that code. I'm using an example from the requests documentation which I have included above. Is there something I am not understanding about HTTPS? The docs seem to suggest that just having the dict defined is enough--and I have been unable to find a resource that suggests otherwise

Comment: @aJetHorn: [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) does not say that the existence of the variable `proxies` is sufficient. Instead the example code provided is this: `requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)` which explicitly sets the proxies for the request. BTW, I have no idea what `self.s` in your code is and what `self.s.update` does.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich self.s is a Session. I have confirmed that on my personal computer the proxy is applied for the request, so I know this is working presumably because all variables in Session are then added to the request.get so they don't have to be re-specified.

Comment: @aJetHorn: I don't see any `update` method in `requests.Session`. It is neither documented nor implemented in the versions of requests I use: `AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'update'
` -  So what should `self.s.update` do in your opinion and why do you think it works this way?

Comment: Update is a method in the session.headers. It updates the dict of headers that is sent. Like I said, I know that that part is working because I've successfully been able to test that my request is getting routed through the proxy IP when testing on my laptop. Last evening, I started running this code on a DigitalOcean droplet, using https, and it works. At this point I strongly believe that there is something, somewhere, on the OS that I have running on godaddy that is preventing this behavior by default.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Further, getting this working on DigitalOcean confirms that, code-wise, this is fine. So now it is more of a dealing-with-Godaddy-bs question. Thank you for helping me drill down to this point.

Comment: Please correct your code then to set `self.s.headers.update` and not `self.s.update`. Also, if this method only sets some request headers it does not change where the underlying socket connects to. This means the underlying socket still connects to the system specified in the URL instead of the proxy. Please use the documented methods to set the proxy and try again. That it worked with digitalocean just might have been luck, probably because no proxy was required there at all so setting some request headers did not make an actual difference.