# Easiest way to use HTTPS through a proxy

Tags: python, ssl, proxy, python-3.6

Requests [doesn't support](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1903#issuecomment-34045255) HTTPS through a proxy, and urllib [doesn't either](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/urllib2.html#proxies) (the provided recipe was created 13 years ago and doesn't work with current Python version, as I'm using Python 3.6).

When trying to connect, both send `b'CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'` to the proxy, and the process is stuck forever. I'm using [this proxy](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py).

In the other hand, cURL is able to send the proper parameters. Using `curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:8899 -v https://example.com`, it sends `b'CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com:443\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.30.0\r\nProxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n'`, and the process continues until cURL receives the proper data. That validates the proxy is working as expected.

Is there an easy way to make HTTPS work with a proxy on Python? I know that I can just use HTTP, but there are some resources that are HTTPS only that I need to access through a proxy.

I don't care much about client security. I have tried dropping SSL verification in both urllib and requests but it still doesn't work.

**Update:** This isn't a duplicate of [Python Requests doesnt work for https proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166334/python-requests-doesnt-work-for-https-proxy) since that only concerns about `requests`, and by the link I posted above, `requests` creator especifically says it doesn't support HTTPS through proxy. What I'm asking is for an alternative to `requests` or `urllib`, not how to make `requests` work (because it doesn't).

Comment: I'd argue that the `curl` implementation is bad since is reveals information that should not be revealed before making an SSL/TLS connections.

Comment: Request supports HTTPS through a proxy. The resource you provide discusses accessing the proxy itself by TLS which is a different thing then using a HTTP proxy for HTTPS (using the CONNECT method). Please provide the code your are using.